# Pydantic how to access updated values for PrivateAttr

Tags: python, pydantic

I have this class

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, PrivateAttr


class A(BaseModel):
    _value: str = PrivateAttr()

    def __init__(self):
        self._value = "Initial Value"
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, some_value: str):
        self._value = some_value

    def clone(self):
        return self.copy(update={"_value": "Updated Value"})
```

When I instantiate one instance and make a copy with a value update, I get the updated value in the copy but when I access the updated value, I still get the initial old value. How can I get the updated value here?

```
a = A()
b = a.clone()
print([a, b])
print(a.value)
print(b.value)
```

For which I get the output

```
[A(), A(_value='Updated Value')]
Initial Value
Initial Value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Private attributes are special and **different** from fields. If you want to properly assign a new value to a private attribute, you need to do it via regular attribute setting:

```py
    ...
    def clone(self):
        obj = self.copy()
        obj._value = "Updated value"
        return obj
```

---

## Long story: `__slots__`, `__dict__`, descriptors & other shenanigans

This an interesting edge case here.

I analyzed this for quite a while and I have to admit that I am still missing one crucial piece, which probably goes pretty deep into the Python data model internals. But please bear with me for a bit of context.

---

#### Private attributes stored in `__slots__`!

The docstring on the `PrivateAttr` function[<sup>1</sup>](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.2/pydantic/fields.py#L1215) tells us a crucial bit of information:

> Private attrs are stored in model `__slots__`.

Looking at the `ModelMetaclass`, we can see the way this is done during class creation[<sup>2</sup>](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.2/pydantic/main.py#L277).

---

#### What happens during `copy`?

I'll reduce and adjust your example code a bit to better illustrate the points I am about to make:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, PrivateAttr

class A(BaseModel):
    _value: str = PrivateAttr(default="Initial Value")
    id: int

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1 = A(id=1)
    a2 = a1.copy(update={"id": 2, "_value": "Updated value"})
    print(a1.__dict__)
    print(a2.__dict__)
```

When we call `copy` on instance `a1`, a dictionary mapping field names to values is set up to be assigned to the [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) of the new instance `a2`. In this case, we additionally pass `update={"_value": "Updated Value"}`, which is "merged" into that dictionary first.

The output we get:

```
{'id': 1}
{'id': 2, '_value': 'Updated value'}
```

Note that for the original object `a1` that you want to copy, the `__dict__` actually only contains the `id`. Its private `_value` attribute is not stored there, it is (as mentioned before) stored in the [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). Yet during creation of the copy `a2` you added `"_value"` to its `__dict__`.

However, the `copy` method does one more thing (via the protected `_copy_and_set_values` method[<sup>3</sup>](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.2/pydantic/main.py#L609)) *after* the `__dict__` is set: It goes over all the private attributes of the "source" instance and copies them over to the newly created instance, but it does so via the regular old [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__), and *not* by directly updating the `__dict__`.

What this means is that we end up with **two distinct** values associated with `_value` on the new object. One `"Updated value"` in its `__dict__` under the `"_value"` key and the other `"Initial value"` (as taken from the source object) being stored in the `__slots__`.

---

#### Precedence in attribute lookup

The documentation's [`__slots__` notes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots) tells us another crucial piece of information:

> `__slots__` are implemented at the class level by creating [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) for each variable name.

Descriptors hold a special place in the attribute lookup logic. What this means is that regular attribute access to a name in the `__slots__` will actually **first** try and get the value from there and thus never even gets to the `__dict__` of the object. There is a really well summarized explanation of this process touching on the precedence of descriptors in this answer to a different question:

[When does Python fall back onto class __dict__ from instance __dict__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399556/when-does-python-fall-back-onto-class-dict-from-instance-dict/72484315#72484315)

In practice, this means that appending `print(a2._value)` to the script from above gives the output `Initial Value`.

Why *exactly* the order of attribute lookup is this way is what I don't fully understand. I assume one would have to check the actual CPython source for that.

But the fact remains that accessing `_value` will check the slots descriptor and thus ignore what has been copied into the object's `__dict__`.

---

#### Why is new value in the object representation?

As you may have guessed by now, the `__repr__` of a model actually iterates through its `__dict__` to grab the key-value-pairs to print. And when there is a key there that is **not** a field (as is the case with `_value`), it is **always** included in the string representation.[<sup>4</sup>](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.2/pydantic/main.py#L913)

This is why doing `print(a1); print(a2)` will give the following output:

```
id=1
id=2 _value='Updated value'
```

---

#### Side note: Avoid properties setters here!

This has nothing to do with the main issue here, but just fyi Pydnatic has problems with property setters. This was discussed [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1577) and is still relevant. Depending on your use case, you may want to utilize one of the workarounds other people posted there.

But I would strongly suggest that you consider using a normal field instead of a private attribute, if you want to set it from the outside anyway. Private attributes should probably be for *internal* use and not mutated from the outside. I struggle to see a use case for this, but you do you.

---

#### Conclusion

To set `_value` on the new object, you should *not* use the `update` parameter, but you need to do it the old fashioned way:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, PrivateAttr

class A(BaseModel):
    _value: str = PrivateAttr(default="Initial value")
    id: int

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    def clone(self):
        obj = self.copy(update={"id": self.id + 1})
        obj._value = "Updated value"
        return obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1 = A(id=1)
    a2 = a1.clone()
    print([a1, a2])
    print(a1.value)
    print(a2.value)
```

Output:

```
[A(id=1), A(id=2)]
Initial value
Updated value
```